# Elasticsearch partial matching on postal address and customer number

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am trying to partially match a search term to the given schema for autocomplete. I'd like customerNumber and AddressLine1 and Zip to match any document that starts with 419 (so 4191 should match customer number 41915678 and address 4191 Board Street and zip code 41912)

```
"mappings": {
    "companyName": {
        "type": "text"
    },
    "customerNumber": {
        "type": "long"
    }
    "address": {
        "addressLine1": {
            "type": "text"
        },
        "city": {
            "type": "text"
        },
        "state": {
            "type": "text"
        },
        "zip": {
            "type": "text"
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone got a neat solution to the query? Eventually I would need to convert this query to C# using NEST client.

Comment: What kind of data volume do you have approximately?

Comment: You can use prefix query (slow on query time) or edge n-grams in the mapping (slow on indexing time).

Comment: 900k records but pretty static data.

Comment: Can anyone assist with n-gram query ? Slow indexing time is more acceptable than slowness on query time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way to do it is to leverage the [`completion` suggester field type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters.html#completion-suggester).

Basically, you can modify your mapping by adding a [`completion` field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters.html#completion-suggester-mapping) in your mapping, such as

```
  "suggest": {
    "type": "completion"
  },
```

However, the completion field's default analyzer (i.e. the [`simple` analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-simple-analyzer.html)) doesn't index numbers, we need to create our custom analyzer that will properly do it:

```
PUT my-index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "suggest_analyzer": {         <--- custom analyzer
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "classic",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      ...,
      "suggest": {                    <--- the new completion field with the right analyzer
        "type": "completion",
        "analyzer": "suggest_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And then you simply need to populate your index by adding all the values you want suggestions on in the suggest field, like below:

```
PUT my-index/_doc/1
{
  "address": {
    "addressLine1": "1234 Main Street",
    "zip": "34526"
  },
  "customerNumber": "41915678",
  "suggest": [
    "1234 Main Street",
    "34526",
    "41915678"
  ]
}
PUT my-index/_doc/2
{
  "address": {
    "addressLine1": "4191 Board Street",
    "zip": "45263"
  },
  "customerNumber": "45267742",
  "suggest": [
    "4191 Board Street",
    "45263",
    "45267742"
  ]
}
PUT my-index/_doc/3
{
  "address": {
    "addressLine1": "5662 4th Avenue",
    "zip": "41912"
  },
  "customerNumber": "24442561",
  "suggest": [
    "5662 4th Avenue",
    "41912",
    "24442561"
  ]
}
```

Then, you can search for `419` using the following suggest query:

```
POST my-index/_search
{
  "suggest": {
    "customer-suggest": {
      "prefix": "419",
      "completion": {
        "field": "suggest"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And you will get all three documents, because each one will have one field that matches `419`

Comment: Thanks, initial run seems to be working as expected. Is there anyway to get the results in the "hits" node of the response instead of the "suggest" ?

Comment: The completion suggester works differently than regular search queries, i.e. it doesn't work off the inverted indexes, but from what they call a finite state transducer (FST) which is fully loaded into memory, hence the speed. So the results are not mixed with hits. You can also try to the use the [`search_as_you_type`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-as-you-type.html) field type which will work off regular queries and return the results in the hits section.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the solution.